# How to extract .nsh file?

Tags: decompress, game-hacking, graphics

I am trying to edit the graphics on a game and have a .nsh file where post-process effect data is contained. I cannot seem to find a program to extract/read its contents.

Googling it, I see something about NSIS packages but nothing past that.

Edit: Link added for the file. This is for Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 Full Burst HD on PC (dx11), and I have also uploaded the corresponding nsh files for ps3, xbox360, ps4, and dx9 (win32)
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17JZi-H8DpZZsOcyTZ_xQUvrgV-cnmnbd?usp=sharing

Comment: Such file extensions are usually useless, unless they are shared by multiple games (and have been dissected before). Add a link to such a file to your post (but providing more files would be more helpful). What kind of data format do you hope to retrieve? What should "post-process effect data" look like? Graphic shaders?

Comment: yes, I am hoping to extract some editable text based files which govern the graphical effects of the game. Specifically things like bloom and motion blur. This is for Naruto Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 Full Burst HD on PC, and I have also uploaded the corresponding nsh files for ps3, xbox360, ps4, and dx9 (win32).

Answer (score 2):

The files you linked, whilst all having an `NSH` extension actually appear to be slightly different archive formats.

Each of these archive file appears to contains a number of graphics shaders compiled to bytecode for the various architectures. The binary formats of these shaders vary significantly between architectures.

A couple have very obvious clues detailing the version of the shader compilers (and hence formats) used -

```
nuccPostEffect_win32.nsh      Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 9.29.952.3111
nuccPostEffect_dx11.nsh       Microsoft (R) HLSL Shader Compiler 6.3.9600.16384
```

The shaders in the dx11 file can be identifed easily as they begin with the magic bytes `DXBC`.  One resource for understanding these is [here](http://timjones.io/blog/archive/2015/09/02/parsing-direct3d-shader-bytecode).

Answer (score 0):

.NSH is only a windows installer format provided/designed by NSIS. The reason why you can't extract the file is because it has been compressed by NSIS (Nullsoft Scriptable Install System) software.

This is most likely the best source for your solution:

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Can_I_decompile_an_existing_installer

I apologize for not having enough time to pick the important info for you. But I am more than honest that this documentation will solve your problem!

Hope I Helped.